# Sort table according to another vector

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, indexing

```
a=[44;60;11]; b=[9;8;4]; c=[4;16;23];
T=table(a,b,c);
d=[2;3;1];
```

Sort rows of table T according to index vector "d"

Comment: What do you mean for rows? Your table output consists of a single row here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're sorting the rows according to the indices in your vector d.

```
tSort = T(d,:);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, this should work as intended:

```
a=[44;60;11]; b=[9;8;4]; c=[4;16;23];
T=table(a,b,c);
d=[2;3;1];

T_new = T(:,d);
```

The last line will swap the table columns (to be exact, the table variables) according to the indices in vector d.